# socket.io v1.1 beforeSend?

Tags: socket.io, socket.io-1.0

Is there a way to globally and automatically modify a message before emitting it? Something along the lines of jQuery ajax's `beforeSend`.

Right now, I'm manually adding a timestamp to the payload for each `emit` and it would be much less error-prone to have that done automatically.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either override the `.emit()` method (saving the original so you can call it) or if you control all the code that calls `.emit()`, then just make your own method that adds the timestamp to the payload and then calls `.emit()`.

To patch the original `.emit()`, you could do this:

```
(function() {
    var origEmit = Socket.prototype.emit;
    Socket.prototype.emit = function(msg, data) {
        if (typeof data === "object") {
            data.timeStamp = Date.now();
        }
        return origEmit.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})();
```

To create your own emit method that all your code could use, you could do this:

```
 Socket.prototype.emitT = function(msg, data) {
    if (typeof data === "object") {
        data.timeStamp = Date.now();
    }
    return this.emit.apply(this, arguments);
 }
```

Comment: Yes, looks like it has to be this way at this point. I was hoping for a built-in hook to avoid having to do monkey patching or writing wrapper function.